# Declare and use internal table like an array of integers

Tags: abap

I want to create an "integer array". Most of the examples use structures so I am not able to derive these for my matter.

```
data: itab type STANDARD TABLE OF i, 
        var type i. 
field-symbols:
        <fs> type i.

do 3 times.
  var = sy-index.
  append var to itab.
enddo.


loop at itab assigning <fs>.
  write var.
endloop.
```

How can I fill it with the numbers of 1 to 3?

How can I print the whole table?

How can I use the index to print one element?

Comment: Your program actually fills the numbers 1 to 3, as you can see in debug. But the display is buggy (you display `var` but you should display `<fs>`).

Answer (score 3):

Variable definition ([DATA ... TABLE OF](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapdata_itab.htm)):

```
DATA integers TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF i
  WITH EMPTY KEY.
```

Filling with values ([VALUE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) or [INSERT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapinsert_itab.htm)):

```
* either fixed values
integers = VALUE #( ( 1 ) ( 2 ) ( 3 ) ).

* or with range of numbers
DO 3 TIMES.
  INSERT sy-index INTO TABLE integers.
ENDFO.
```

Print out, one row per line:

```
LOOP AT integers INTO DATA(int).
  WRITE / int.
ENDLOOP.
```

Access second entry via a [table expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_expressions.htm):

```
DATA(second_int) = integers[ 2 ].
```

Using an unstructured [row type](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrow_type_glosry.htm) - in this case simply “i” - and the addition “[with empty key](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenitab_empty_key.htm)” is nearest to what we find as arrays in other programming languages.

Finally, you can pass „arrays“ just like any other data type ([TYPES ... TABLE OF](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptypes_itab.htm)):

```
TYPES integer_array TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF i
  WITH EMPTY KEY.

METHODS sum
  IMPORTING
    integers TYPE integer_array
  RETURNING
    VALUE(result) TYPE i.
```

Comment: thank you! I have one more question how can I use an internal table as parameter for a method? I tried: data intarray type STANDARD TABLE OF i with empty key.

method summearray.
  data summef type i value 0.
  loop at intarray into data(int).
  summef = summef + int.
  endloop.
  summe=summef.
  endmethod.

I got the errormessage "intarray" is no internal table.

Comment: Added it to the answer. Declare the type beforehand. Although I am pretty sure there are some suitable prefabricated types in Badis packages that would fit as well.